# SQL statement to conditionally selecting records based on the previous record

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables as below

**Table 1** : Animal (ID is a primary key)

```
ID  |Animal
----------
1   |Dog
2   |Cat
3   |Fish
4   |Bird
5   |Elephant
```

**Table 2**: Pet (ID here is foreign keys to the `Animal` table)

```
ID | Animal | Name
----------
1 | Dog | Annie
1 | Dog | Buckie
2 | Cat | Conner
2 | Cat | Kitten
3 | Fish| Lala
```

I want to write a SQL statement to append a row with "Fish" right after wherever a specific pet "Dog" appears without breaking the order.

Expected result should be:

```
ID | Animal | Name
----------
1 | Dog | Annie
3 | Fish| NULL 
1 | Dog | Buckie
3 | Fish| NULL
2 | Cat | Conner
2 | Cat | Kitten
3 | Fish| Lala
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want and how exactly should it behave. Why do you append a row with "Fish" which has `ID = 3` but `name` is null? What if you have more than one fish in your `Pet` table? Which should the alogirthm choose then?

Comment: Hi, It is just an example and the real case is much more complicated. The idea is Fish has its unique ID and it doesn't matter if I have more than 1 fish in the Pet table or not.

Comment: Result order of rows depends only on "order by" clause !!!

Comment: The logic should be we will select the `fish` with `ID = 3` from the table `Animal` . and in the table `Pet` , whenever I have a row `Animal = Dog , ID=1` the output a record set will have to attach a a row `Animal = Fish, ID=3` right after that.

Comment: Hi @Mike  I understand the result might be depend on order by clause, but we can always make use of an extra column to sort by order within the SELECT statement

Comment: Note: the `pet` table does not have a Primary Key, and the `Animal` column is redundant. But of course the actual problem is much more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about `Oracle11g` but I think it has `ROW_NUMBER`.

You could add a row number to the original table,
and then union a fish table with corresponding row numbers.

For example

```
WITH Tablex AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, Name) AS ref_id, *
    FROM your_table
    )
SELECT ID, Animal, Name
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Tablex
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        (SELECT ref_id, 3 AS ID, 'Fish' AS Animal, NULL AS Name
         FROM TableX
         WHERE Animal = 'Dog'
         ) x
     ) X
ORDER BY ref_id, id
```

As commented above, the order of rows depends only on the `ORDER BY` clause and the order may not be actually incorporated in the table (if you put it `INTO` something).

Answer (score 0):

```
with Q as (
  select ID, Animal, Name,
         row_number() over (order by id, name) rnum
    from Pet
)
select ID, Animal, Name, rnum 
  from Q

union all

select 3, 'Fish', NULL, rnum+0.5
  from Q
 where ID=1 and name in('Annie','Buckie')
 order by rnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select tn.Id 
    , case when tt.rn = 0 then tn.Animal else 'Fish' end Animal
    , case when tt.rn = 0 then tn.Name else NULL end Name
    , tn.rn+tt.rn  rn
from (
    select ID, Animal, Name,  2 * row_number() over (order by id, name) as rn
    from pet
    ) tn
join (
     select 0 rn from dual union
     select 1 from dual
) tt on tt.rn <= case Animal when 'Dog' then 1 else 0 end
order by tn.rn+tt.rn;
```